# Fórmula de taxa de juros

Tags: php

Eu tenho que fazer este pequeno trabalho em PHP estruturado abaixo, mas estou com um problema ali na formula da taxa de juros, não entendi direito como aplicar, eu fiz assim:

```
/* Calcula os Juros
------------------------------------------------------------- */
function juros($dados){
    $r = (($dados['preco'] * (1 + $dados['txjuros']) ^ $dados['parcelas'] ) * $dados['txjuros']) / ((1 + $dados['txjuros']) ^ $dados['parcelas'] - 1);
    return $r;
}
```

A fórmula correta está na imagem abaixo:
[image: fórmulas de taxa de juros]

---

**Segunda tentativa:**

Fiz um algoritmo com uma fórmula diferente, mas então os juros ficaram com o valor fixo, independente da quantidade de parcelas.

O valor dos juros deveria subir tantos % em cima do valor de cada parcelas.

Se eu coloco 4 parcelas é o mesmo valor de juros que se eu colocar 10 parcelas, então é errado assim, deveria setar valor x de juros para primeira parcela e valor y de juros para segunda parcela.

Alguem pode me ajudar analisando meu código, o erro deve estár na logica de aplicar a formula concediade pelo professor.

Código PHP:

http://pastebin.com/rGFAxUyR

Comment: André, limite-se a um tópico por pergunta. Mesmo que tenham o conhecimento em matemática financeira, sua pergunta está fora do contexto do site.

Comment: Amigo, me diga o que tens que calcular para eu te falar qual a expressão que tens que usar...

Comment: Porque você colocou a expressão que está usando, porém não colocou qual o objetivo dela. Então não tem como a gente dizer se tá correta ou não...

Comment: A aplicação não vai dar certo nunca pois está sendo feita uma divisão do MONTANTE pelo DESCONTO

Answer (score 9):

Para elevar algum número a outro troque o `^` pela função [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

```
 (1 + $dados['txjuros']) ^ $dados['parcelas']
```

Troque por:

```
 pow( (1 + $dados['txjuros']), $dados['parcelas'])
```

Comment: Entendi sua formula, mas eu estou aplicando de forma errada, poderia me informar se o valor que ela retorna seria o total ou apenas os juros ? Pois me retornou um valor alto demais para ser um resultado correto.

Answer (score 4):

A partir do PHP 5.6 podemos utilizar o operador para [exponenciação](https://www.php.net/language.operators.arithmetic).

```
$r = (($dados['preco'] * (1 + $dados['txjuros']) ** $dados['parcelas']) * $dados['txjuros']) / ((1 + $dados['txjuros']) ** $dados['parcelas'] - 1);
```

Comment: Entendi sua formula, mas eu estou aplicando de forma errada, poderia me informar se o valor que ela retorna seria o total ou apenas os juros ? Pois me retornou um valor alto demais para ser um resultado correto.

Comment: A formula da sua pergunta que está errada então.